# black box and inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Hello Stackoverflowers,

Imagine the following Base class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array
{
  private ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();

  public void add(Object element)
  {
    a.add(element);
  }

  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
      a.add(elements[i]); // this line is going to be changed
  }
}
```

And here’s the Derived class:

```
public class ArrayCount extends Array
{
  private int count = 0;

  @Override
  public void add(Object element)
  {
    super.add(element);
    ++count;
  }

  @Override
  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    super.addAll(elements);
    count += elements.length;
  }
}
```

The Array add() adds an element to a local ArrayList.
The Array addAll() calls the local ArrayList add for each element.

The ArrayCount add() calls its parent’s add() and then increments the count.
The ArrayCount addAll() calls its parent’s addAll() and then increments the count by the number of elements.

Now for the breaking change. The commented line of code in the Base class is changed to the following:

```
  public void addAll(Object elements[])
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
      add(elements[i]); // this line was changed
  }
```

Now ArrayCount addAll() calls its parent’s addAll() which internally calls the add() which has been overriden by the Derived class.

The author of the Derived class must know how the Base class has been implemented. And they must be informed about every change in the Base class since it could break their Derived class in unpredictable ways.

I'm looking for a correct way to implement this that would respect black box programming concept. Because this exemple force the writter of the derivated class to know how the base class is implemented and know every change

Comment: The change in the base class is explicitly changing the contract by making the invocation virtual and delegating implementation to derived classes.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Is there a way to do what? Please clarify your need

Comment: It's unclear indeed. I edited the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by "Black Box" you mean: "Implementer of the derived class must not know about the implementation details of the base class Array". I would opt for a decorator using delegation as probably being the better approach:

```
public class ArrayCount {
  private int   count = 0;
  private Array a;

  public ArrayCount(Array a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public void add(Object element) {
    a.add(element);
    ++count;
  }

  public void addAll(Object elements[]) {
    a.addAll(elements);
    count += elments.length;
  }

}
```

*Note: I left out input param checking for brevity.*

If both `Array` and `ArrayCount` implement the same interface, e.g. `IArray`, you can still use the classes interchangeably:

```
interface IArray {
 public void add(Object element);
 public void addAll(Object elements[]);
}
...
Array implements IArray {...}
ArrayCount implements IArray {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the base class methods as final but include supporting methods for extension.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array {
    private final ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public final void add(Object element) {
        a.add(element);
        afterAdd(element);
    }

    public final void addAll(Object[] elements) {
        for (Object element : elements) {
            a.add(element);
        }
        afterAddAll(elements);
    }

    protected void afterAddAll(Object[] elements) {
        return;
    }

    protected void afterAdd(Object element) {
        return;
    }
}
```

so a subclass can only override the support methods

```
public class ArrayCount extends Array {
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void afterAdd(Object element) {
        ++count;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterAddAll(Object[] elements) {
        count += elements.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the *Black box* approach you just call method of an object and so you don't care about how it is implemented.

The public method of a Class is a *contract* that define what you provide and what you get.

The developer that maintain the Class could change anything but the *contract* or the method signatures.

If you extend a Class, and you're going to override a method or more methods, than you should care about the Class implementation, as you are going to specialize some behaviors of the Class.

To have a clean separation of different classes that have same interface, you should use the java *interface*, so each developer could do the own implementation of the business logic.

You could design a Class to be extendable from someone else, when you know that some method could be specialized.

But if you don't want that, you could decide that the method could not be overridden by defining those method *final*.

In this way you are telling to other developers that will use your code that you don't want to extend some behaviors.